# Are SAP clients 000, 001, 066 present in all environments?

Tags: sap-basis

As it is known that in SAP system there are 000, 001, 066 as default clients.

Suppose we do have separate systems for Development, Quality assurance and production so will those 3 default clients be present in all the systems?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these clients will exist in all SAP Netweaver ABAP systems.

Each client has specific roles:

- Client 000 is the main admin client, where your basis team will install/upgrade the system.
- Client 001 is a copy of client 000 which was created during the installation of the system.
- Client 066 is used by EWA (Early Watch Alerts), if it's configured on your SLD (System Landscape Domain). This client is not mandatory anymore after 7.40 as explained below.

That's necessary too for a maintenance planner at SAP site.

It's possible to remove clients 001 and 066 as explained in [note 1749142 - How to remove unused clients including client 001 and 066](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1749142/E) and the same is publicly available in this [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/06/how-to-remove-unused-clients-including-client-001-and-066/). This note & post also say that:

> SAP NetWeaver 7.40 is the last release delivering the client 066 with the installation or upgrade.

Comment: I edited the post to mention the client 001 + references added + 001 & 066 can be removed

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are part of the standard install for all instances.

Answer (score -1):

All these clients(000,001 and 066) are created by default when you install any SAP system.

These clients will be present in all dev,test and production as well